# TypeScript: so how exactly is "this" scoped?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this piece of Typescript code:

```
constructor($triggerHref: JQuery) {
        // stuff...
        var _this = this;
        $(document).on("click",$triggerHref.selector,e=>{
            e.preventDefault();
            var target = $(e.srcElement).attr("data-pcc-sort-trigger");
            if (target == _this.active)
                _this.load(target, !_this.isDescending);
            else _this.load(target, false);
        });

    }
```

If I remove the `var _this = this;` line and just use `this` inside the event handler, the generated js code looks reasonably the same (it generates the _this anyway), yet for some reason `this.active` and `this.load()` are undefined.

My understanding of TS's scoping was that `()=>{}` methods keep the `this` from their parents, and only `function(){}` methods work like usual JS methods.

So why is this one not working for me?

Comment: Your understanding is correct and the generated code is identical for me when I try this.  What differences are you seeing?

Comment: @JohnnyHK: in debugger the `this` gets resolved to the object wrapped in `$triggerHref`, and then the code exists on the `(target == undefined)` line WITHOUT throwing an exception. With putting the `this` there manually, everything works as intended.

Comment: @JcFx: does that actually matter??

Comment: Can you post a more complete example?

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh: I'll provide one (with step-by-step repro) later, in my free time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already noticed, lambda functions capture `this` at the time the lambda function is defined. This can lead to wierd results (also there are a [few](http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/361) [bugs](http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/11) around `var _this = this`), although most of these seems to be fixed.

The whole language construct seems to be for the purpose of cheating JavaScript scoping (`this` is the object that the function is called on).

As for the weirdness you explained (this.active and _this.active behaving differently), there is no explanation inside the scope of the question.

The generated JavaScript (as you have stated) should be (nearly) the same. Well apart from writing `var _this = this;` leading to `_this` defined more than once in the same scope and breaking javascript validity. This is a problem around TypeScript lambdas. Never define `_this` in TS as it is reserved for some purposes (and not checked if it's free).

And there is no magic in TypeScript. What gets executed is the JavaScript it generates. Check if something overwrites `_this` in the same scope (which would be easy to spot since the scope of `var _this` is the scope of the constructor function, also `var` hides the variables with the same name coming from an outer scope, so it should be inside the constructor).

I avoid using lambda expressions in TypeScript for now. Using simple anonym functions instead, does not require you to restructure any of your code. Saving `this` to an other variable can be considered ugly yes, but you can work around it by using [$.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) for example. This way you can even write a regex replace to change your lambdas to $.proxy(). For now.

So all in all I would need to debug the generated JS to spot the error since your code should be syntactically fine. It seems to me that the TypeScript compiler needs some rethinking around this (I hope some TS enthusiasts will differ and teach me how it is properly done, as I'm not agains TS, on the contrary).

I'm pretty sure @RyanCavanaugh would be able to prepare a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The lambda expression generates a function expression, so the same rules for scope applies to a lambda expression as a function expression.</strike>

Example:

```
var x = e => {};
```

genrates this Javascript code:

```
var x = function (e) {
};
```

Comment: I thought when you used arrow notation in TypeScript is also scoped the `this` inside it to the context of where you created it. Am I thinking of a different notation that does that?

Comment: @Chad: Actually, I have to take all that back. When used *inside an object*, the lambda expression also results in a `_this` variable being created, and all references to `this` would be changed to `_this`. I don't know why that wouldn't work in your case.